# spark on yarn, Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I was writing a spark program in my developing machine, which is a mac. 
The version of hadoop is 2.6, the version of spark is 1.6.2. The hadoop cluster have 3 nodes, of course all in linux machine.
I run the spark program in idea IDE in spark standalone mode, it works successfully. But now, I change it to yarn-client mode, it doesn't work successfully, and gives the message as follows:

```
...
2017-02-23 11:01:33,725-[HL] INFO main org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
2017-02-23 11:01:34,839-[HL] INFO main org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2017-02-23 11:01:35,842-[HL] INFO main org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2017-02-23 11:01:36,847-[HL] INFO main org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2017-02-23 11:01:37,854-[HL] INFO main org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
...
```

I have already added corresponding configuration files to the resources directory of the project. If I make it a jar package and use `spark-submit` to run this program, it will be ok. Now, I want to run this program in IDE  as yarn-client mode, just like spark standalone mode. How can I fix this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Ensure the YARN configurations are available for Spark to use when running in yarn mode. Add these files `core-site.xml`, `hdfs-site.xml` and `yarn-site.xml` files to the `conf` directory of spark. 
Also make sure, the `yarn-site.xml` contains the address of the resource manager

```
<property>
   <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
   <value>resource_manager_ip:8032</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Do you mean I should have the same configuration flies in the develop machine as the running yarn cluster?

Comment: The configurations of which running yarn environment you want spark to use. If you want to run `yarn-client` in the develop machine, you must have yarn running in the develop machine and those configurations must be copied to spark as well (or setting `YARN_CONF_DIR` will do) or provide the conf of a remote yarn environment which is accessible by the spark in develop machine.

Comment: I did the follows but didn't work. 1. Run a local hadoop and spark in my develop machine, and their configurations is different from remote hadoop and spark. 2. Copy remote hadoop's configurations to remote spark's `conf` directory, including `yarn-site.xml, core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml` three files. 3. Copy remote hadoop's configurations to local spark's `conf` directory, also  including `yarn-site.xml, core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml` three files. 4. In my project, I didn't add other configurations.

Comment: Goto `http://resourcemanager:8088/conf` and check for the property `yarn.resourcemanager.address`. The value should not be `0.0.0.0`. If it is a valid IP and Spark is still trying to connect to Resourcemanager at `0.0.0.0`, then spark is not reading the correct configurations

Comment: This helped. Am using HDP 3.1 and by default Ambari has yarn.resourcemanager.address=<fqdn>:8050. So setting something like `conf.set("spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.address", "HW01.co.local:8050")` fixed the problem for me (rather than changing the YARN configs for the cluster just to get spark working).

Answer (score 2):

Set your conf object like this, its work for me:

```
conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(setup.getAppname).setMaster("yarn")
            .set("spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.hostname", "resourcemanager.fqdn")
            .set("spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.address", "resourcemanager.fqdn:8032")`
```

Font: [hortonworks.com](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/59289/cannot-connect-to-resource-manager.html)