# Spark: How to obtain the location of configurations spark is using?

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Right now, I am running into the following [issue exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42409307/spark-on-yarn-connecting-to-resourcemanager-at-0-0-0-08032).  Specifically, `spark-submit` is attempting to connect to the `yarn.resourcemanager` at location `0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0`.

I have checked all of the logs delineated in the stack overflow thread above.  They all seem to be correct. I have also added in a `yarn.resourcemanager.address=...` line to the default settings files at the top of the spark configuration directories, exported `YARN_CONF_DIR` and all of the other fixes listed on that thread.

At the bottom of the comments in the top rated answer, a commentator pointed out that if none of the above fixes work, then spark is not using the correct configurations.

---

At this point, I am pretty sure that my spark install is not using the correct configurations (I did not install it).

How does one go about determining which configurations `spark` *is* using, and how does one change them to the correct configurations? (or maybe I just need to reboot the machine?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spark-shell for example, I can do this:

```
scala> getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("yarn-site.xml")
res1: java.net.URL = file:/etc/spark2/conf.cloudera.spark2_on_yarn/yarn-conf/yarn-site.xml
```

...and the result shows the exact resolved location of a config file from my current classpath. Same could be easily translated to Java (almost verbatim) if your application is Java-based.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to access creationSite field on org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession through debugger or through reflection. Then you can try to find class and place in code where your spark session is created and then you can try to find how org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.Builder is called.